# Sharing mounted CIFS filesystem with samba to macOS users

Tags: linux, mac-osx, samba, cifs, samba4

I have a CIFS filesystem which I am trying to share over samba with macOS users. I can't directly connect to the original samba share which I'm mounting as the CIFS fs on the server as I have to change samba configs and I don't have access to the original Samba Server.

As of now everything works as intended. Every user has their own folder with simulated ownership (cifs option uid and guid) and permissions to write into those folders.

The problem is, when connecting with macOS Finder, and trying to copy files to the share, the result is error code -50 (unexpected error).

But the weird thing is, I can copy files to the share manually with cli programs (I tried cp, mv and dd and all of them copy the files without an issue). Finder can't create files in the share but it can create folders for whatever reason and it can also move existing files to other folders.

I don't know how to debug this issue. I can't even find details for the unexpected error in Finder.